# Building a reusable component to map through different sets of data React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

Just like the title says I'm passing down pokemon data and rickandmorty data. I also happen to be using the tailwind select menu for react thats pretty long. Is there a better way to do it than conditionally map through the data? I know I can do this

```
{pokemons ? (
            {pokemons?.map((pokemon, idx) => (
              **30 line long code for the select menu**
            ))}
         
        ) : (
            {rickAndMorty?.map((character, idx) => (
              **Another 30 long line code for the select menu**
            ))}
        )}
```

Is this the only way to do it or is there a cleaner way? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Are the 30 lines long code in both places the same? If different, how different?

Comment: The code is the same but the props and nested keys are different. For pokemon, I just have to do ```{pokemon}``` to show pokemon names but for rick and morty i have to do ```{character.name}``` to show rick and morty names.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to try and separate any duplicated code out into some generic component, like:

```
const GenericSelectItem = (props)=>{
    return (<>{/* props.itemValues */}</>);
};

const GenericSelectList = (props)=>{
    const { selectItems } = props;
    return (<SelectList>
        { selectItems.map( selectItem => <GenericSelectItem selectItem={ selectItem } /> ) }
    </SelectList>);
};

const Example = (props)=>{
    const itemsToDisplay = pokemons || rickAndMorty;
    return (<>
        { !itemsToDisplay ? null : <GenericSelectList selectItems={ itemsToDisplay } /> }
    </>);
};
```

In case the SelectItems are very different, add specific components, like:

```
const PokemonItem = (props)=>{
    return (<GenericSelectItem>{/* pokemon specific variations */}</GenericSelectItem>);
};

const RickAndMortyItem = (props)=>{
    return (<GenericSelectItem>{/* rickAndMorty specific variations */}</GenericSelectItem>);
};
```